# Bash script check string for uppercase letter

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, git-bash, uppercase

I am trying to check a string for any Uppercase letter. my code shows NO UPPER for any input, may it be "sss", "Sss", "SSS"

```
if [[ "$pass" =~ [^a-zA-Z0-9] ]]
then
   echo "Upper found"
else
   echo "no upper"
fi
```

Comment: What is it you think that regex matches? Why do you have lowercase letters `a-z` and digits `0-9` in it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]` means anything except for `a-z`, i.e. lowercase letters, `A-Z`, i.e. uppercase letters, and `0-9`, i.e. digits. `sss`, `Sss`, `SSS` all contain just letters, so they can't match.

```
[[ $password =~ [A-Z] ]]
```

is true if the password contains any uppercase letter.

You should set `LC_ALL`before running this kind of tests, as for example

```
$ LC_ALL=cs_CZ.UTF-8 bash -c '[[ č =~ [A-Z] ]] && echo match'
match
$ LC_ALL=C           bash -c '[[ č =~ [A-Z] ]] && echo match'
# exit-code: 1
```

`[[:upper:]]` should work always.

Comment: for lowercase and number only, it'll be [^a-z^0-9]

Comment: Do you have to use the `[[ ]]` syntax? I tried using `test $foo =~ [A-Z]` but it didn't work. I got the error `test: =~: binary operator expected`

Comment: Yes, `test` and `[` don't support the `=~` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong. Use [A-Z] or [:upper:].

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: a hint for you: `[:upper:]` and all other similar only represent classes, to match, you need an extra layer of bracket over them. so `[A-Z]` is equivalent to `[[:upper:]]`

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: Equivalent under some settings of `locale`.

Comment: No regex is involved here. Bash has its own syntax for globbing although it shares some characteristics with regex.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this script no matter how I ran it, until I changed it to let my input string be $1, and then set pass=$1. I also changed the regex a bit. What I finally got to work correctly is below. Then I could run bash (script) John and get a valid response. Hope this helps.

```
pass=$1
if [[ "$pass" =~ ^[A-Z] ]]
then
   echo "Upper found"
else
   echo "No Upper"
fi
```